# sftp stuck when not existing directory called

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, sftp

When I try to fetch files via sftp in shell script:

1. It's working fine when all called directory present.
2. It's stuck once its deal with non existing directories.

   ```
   sshpass -p 'password' sftp -oBatchMode=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -b - user1@www.ftp.com 1>$currentdir/listfiles.log << !
   cd /Root/work/in/abc/
   -mget *.* 
   cd /Root/work/in/def/
   -mget *.*
   bye
   !
   ```

Above is code snipped can you suggest solution. Greatly appreciate!!

Comment: I don't think you can do this as a bash script, since it can't check for error messages. Use Expect, or a programming language with an SFTP library.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, Here do we have any mechanism to check if then else test to check directory?

Comment: `sftp` is not really designed for scripting, it's for interactive use. Use a real programming language, it can do these tests.